# Why is #create failing on this FactoryGirl object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, factory-bot

I am trying to test the Quotes#create controller action but am having trouble understanding a failure. I am using Devise and FactoryGirl and the Quotes model belongs_to :user. The rspec failure message is `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"quotes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`. The FactoryGirl created Quote object is passed the user:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:quote) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user) }
```

It seems that neither the record is being saved in the database, nor therfore can the records [:id] be passed back to be rendered to the show action.

Any guidance appreciated.

quotes_controller.rb

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy ]
  before_action :owners_only, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy ]

  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
  end

  def create
    # @quote = @user.quotes.new(quote_params)
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
        redirect_to quote_url(@quote), notice: 'Quote request created'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @quote.update_attributes(quote_params)
      redirect_to quote_path(@quote)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @quote.destroy
    redirect_to quotes_path
  end

private

  def quote_params
    params.require(:quote).permit(:gla, :prev_cover, :co_name, :co_number, :postcode, :industry, :lives_overseas, 
                                  :scheme_start_date, :payment_frequency, :commission_level)
  end

  def owners_only
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    if current_user != @quote.user
      redirect_to quotes_path
    end
  end
end
```

quote.rb model:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    enum industry:          [ :financial_services, :architect, :business_consultancy ]
    enum payment_frequency: [ :annually, :monthly ]
end
```

users.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "test#{}@tes.com" }
    password "12345678"

    factory :user2 do
    end
  end
end
```

quotes.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :quote do
    prev_cover true
    sequence(:co_name) { |n| "Acme Co #{n}" }
    co_number 9999
    postcode "al1 1aa"
    industry :financial_services
    lives_overseas true
    scheme_start_date "2018-01-01"
    payment_frequency :monthly
    commission_level 12
    gla 1

    factory :quote2 do
    end
  end
end
```

quote_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe QuotesController, type: :controller do
    describe "signed in user" do

        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:quote) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user) } #user.id not getting through here?

        before do
            sign_in(user)
        end

        describe "POST create" do

            context "valid data" do
                let(:valid_data) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:quote) } #user.id not getting through here?
                it "redirects to quote#show" do
                    post :create, params: { quote: valid_data }
                    expect(response).to redirect_to(quote_path(assigns[:quote]))
                end

                it " creates a new quote in the database" do
                    expect {
                        post :create, params: { quote: valid_data }
                    }.to change(Quote, :count).by(1)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

rspec output:

```
 1) QuotesController signed in user POST create valid data redirects to quote#show
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(quote_path(assigns[:quote]))

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"quotes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/controllers/quotes_controller_spec.rb:46:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) QuotesController signed in user POST create valid data  creates a new quote in the database
     Failure/Error:
       expect {
        post :create, params: { quote: valid_data }
       }.to change(Quote, :count).by(1)

       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/quotes_controller_spec.rb:50:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It seems that the user_id is not getting through with the :valid_data object `let(:valid_data) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:quote) }`. Though the `:quote` object was given the :user object in:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:quote) { FactoryGirl.create(:quote, user: user) }
```

It;s just not getting through, I think this is where the issue lies here, any advice?

Comment: What do you get with `if @quote.save!` in your controller?

Comment: I get a record invalid `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: User must exist
     # ./app/controllers/quotes_controller.rb:11:in "create"`. Is it the `let(:quote)` has `user: user` passed to the #create, it's just not getting through? Is there another way to lay this out I wonder?

Comment: Or something to do with the #owners_only in quotes_controller.rb perhaps!?

Comment: If a quote belongs to a user, you should create the quote through the user. E.g., `current_user.quotes.new(quote_params)` or `@user` if you don't have a `#current_user` helper method (which  I  recommend!).

Comment: `#owners_only` requires a quote to already exist by id, if you're in a create action there is no `params[:id]` related to a quote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145904/discussion-between-jbk-and-mike-schutte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I recommend changing your create action to:

`def create
  @quote = current_user.quotes.new(quote_params)
  if @quote.save
      redirect_to quote_url(@quote), notice: 'Quote request created'
  else
    render :new
  end
end`

Comment: ` NoMethodError:
       undefined method "quotes" for #<User:0x007fff2bd36170>
       Did you mean?  quoted_id` so apparently unable to use the current_user helper, @user not available in the quote_conrtroller either. Will update fulll code files in folder above.

Comment: In the same way that you have `belongs_to :user`, which gives you a `#user` method on `Quote` instances, you can add a `has_many :quotes` method to the `User` model.

To clarify, `current_user` is available, as you are getting an undefined method error for the `#<User....>` instance, not an undefined method for NilClass.

Comment: omg, how daft, had forgotten to do the `has_many :quotes` in user model. HALLELUJAH. wow, nearly went insane there, thanks Mike, all working now!!!